# Are there any OGC API or OGC WFS servers that work with what ArcGIS Pro terms "On Demand" (and defines as "complex filtering implementing")?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, wfs, ogc-api

I've implemented MapServer's 8.0.0 TinyOWS for (WFST), CrunchyData's pg_featureserv 1.2.0 (OGC API), and GeoServer's 2.21.2 (WFS) services for a point layer I have in PostGIS.  I can get capabilities, metadata, individual features, and attribute tables from all three.

However, they all only work with "Snapshot" in the feature Properties in ArcGIS Pro 2.9 (the full dataset or a random-thin of the full dataset).  When I change it to "On Demand" so that I can only retrieve what is in view extents, there is simply nothing displayed and no attributes.  I've manually made calls to these server implementations with postman and I know that I can either bbox or feature number limit on all three.  (I also know that ArcGIS Pro's Feature Limit works on the properties tab below "Snapshot/On Demand").

Posts from 2017 state that Pro will support extent based querying, and the docs say that "On Demand works but compatibility is less widespread."

At this point all I can guess is to try to intercept the calls that Esri is making to make sure that they're valid calls or malformed, or find the *right* server technology to make sure that I can deliver subsets of data on a feature level.

Comment: The server software choice shouldn't matter if the standard is correctly implemented.

Comment: @nmtoken agreed, unless A) the client, ArcGIS Pro doesn't correctly implement the calls themselves or B) there is something else going on between the client and the web server maybe, such as the POST calls being rejected for example.

Comment: I had a try with GeoServer 2.22RC1 and ArcGIS Pro seems to send GetFeatures with BBOX, and data appear into the map on ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks @user30184.  Was your feature -> properties -> WFS set to snapshot or on demand?

Comment: You asked if some server works with "on demand", so that's what I tested. I think the service must first be added with the default that is snapshot, and only after that the connection can be turned from the layer properties. At least I did not find a way to add a layer with "on demand" option directly.